# Is there a way to ensure that a service/app that I have deployed heroku, stays running during an update?

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, cloud

Currently I am working on deploying a service on Heroku. The service polls an api and uses a regular `setInterval` method in Node.js to do this to get new information (I cannot use a websocket since the api I am using is not mind).

Periodically just like for any program or app that somebody develops, it needs to be updated. My question is what is the best way to update my app on heroku so that when I push a new change to production it does not stop the app from running? The reason is because I don't want to miss new data from the api.

My first thought is to have some sort of redundancy where there are at least 2 servers running the app and as one updates the other runs and vice versa. Yet, I am not sure if this is done automatically by heroku, or if there is not, how can I ensure I set up something like this to not miss a piece of data during an update. Missing even one new piece of data from the API is not an option for us.

Are there other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic process for zero-downtime updates in nodejs or on Heroku.  If you can't or don't want the downtime from updating the source files, then stopping and restarting the server, then you will have to do something like you were already thinking with two separate processes where one keeps running while the other is getting updated and then vice versa.

You haven't said much about what this app does other than polls some external API and you haven't said what it does with the data it gets from that API.  Both of those are relevant to the details of how you would implement this.

I'll make a few assumptions about those unknowns for purposes of illustration.  Let's suppose that this service app just updates a database with the newly found data from the API and does not start any server processes of its own.

In that case, you design your service so you can run two instances and so it accepts a command line argument for whether it should start out polling the API or whether it should just start up and wait.  You give your server its own control port (typically an http server that accepts requests only locally, not from the internet) that lets you send it commands.  And, you make the port that the control port uses configurable, either from a command line argument or an environment variable so that you can start multiple instances of your app, each with a different control port.

Then here's a sequence of events:

1. Start up one instance of your server and pass it the command line argument to tell it to immediately start polling.
2. It runs this way until you have an update ready.
3. Then, when you have an update ready, you update the local code which won't affect the running instance since its code is already loaded.
4. After the update, you start up a second instance of your server (running the new code) and pass it a command line argument telling it not to start polling yet.  At this point, you have two instances of the service running, one (running the old code) is polling the API, the other (running the new code) is on standby.
5. Then, you send each app a command on their control port.  The first app (running the old code) is told to stop polling and shut-down.  The second app (running the new code) is told to start polling.
6. You now have the new code up and running and polling without any interruption.

You can automate this switch-over with your favorite shell script.

If your server also has an incoming http server to serve requests from the internet, then the command that tells the 2nd instance to start polling will also will have to startup its http server for internet requests after the previous instance shut theirs down.

With a load balancer or dynamically configurable proxy, you could have both web servers running on different local ports and dynamically change the load balancer/proxy configuration to route all incoming requests to the 2nd instance before shutting down the 1st instance and not miss any incoming web requests.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth explanation. @jfriend00 I guess in theory I can just run 2 production apps on heroku and update one at a time too also right? Looking for the quickest solution here. Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @MarioLopez - Well, running two apps, you'd have to have some sort of load balancer that would spread the load between them and then put all the requests over to one when you took the other down to upgrade.  But, yes that is how larger sites that have many servers running do their upgrades.

Comment: @MarioLopez - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: Perfect thank you for the response! Just made yours the answer :)

Comment: One other question that came to mind is, a load balancer in theory would only be needed if you are send http request to the server right? But if we are simply updating a database a load balancer is not needed correct?

Comment: @MarioLopez - Well, you presumably have server-side code that uses that database and you're trying to keep your server running and functional so you can't stop the database for an update without incurring server downtime.

Comment: Database is firebase so I was just thinking of have both servers running and if the servers detect there is a duplicate record then we don't add it. That way when I update one we know the other one will continue polling. I am not too familiar with a load balancer use case, in this situation. I thought a load balancer was to handle http traffic.